# JVM track any objection creation

Tags: java, jvm, jvm-arguments

Many times I've seen some people tracked how the VM creates objects and how it performs optimization (eg: String concatenation). Unfortunately I can't find the correct command. Does anyone know?

Comment: jmc, jprofiler, yourkit

Answer (score 0):

The best tool for this kind f investigation is to use a profiler.  I would start with Flight Recorder to record object allocations and CPU consumption and where this is happening.